# Is there any automatic way to normalise google sheet data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset with more than 3000 rows and I have some columns in this format 

( A / B / C )==Table (1)
and I want to normalize each row with specific ID == Table (2):

[image: 0]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63193639/

Answer (score 1):

```
={X1:Y1, "ID_RF", Z1; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "where Col3 !=''"), TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "where Col3 !=''"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label count(Col2)''"), 
 ",")&",", QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "where Col3 !=''"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label count(Col2)''"))), 
 ","))&COUNTIFS(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "select Col2 where Col3 !=''"), 
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "select Col2 where Col3 !=''"), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
 COUNTA(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "select Col2 where Col3 !=''")))), "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "select Col2 where Col3 !=''")))))}, "select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3"))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Do you know you have 2 similar answers on this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(X2:X), "♠"&X2:X&"♦"&Y2:Y&"♦"&SPLIT(Z2:Z, "/"), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "where Col3 !=''"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score -1):

I had similar requirement like the below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEqLN.png

Data need to be split from colD, below is the formula which has been used.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(C5:C), "♠"&C5:C&"♦"&SPLIT(D5:D, ","), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "where Col2 !=''"))`

Comment: Please explain why this is an answer. Answers that are just code fragments are disouraged as poor quality. [answer] [help] Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This adds nothing to the previous answers. It is exactly the same code as another answer using different table origin. It is not helpful.